# Шаблоны в C++ Ограничение типа

Tags: c++

Есть шаблон, например : `template <typename T>`

Подскажите, как мне ограничить тип, чтобы `typename` было только либо `int`, либо `double`.

Comment: почитайте про SFINAE C++

Comment: @Abyx а это так важно?

Comment: @Abyx можно пример, демонстрирующий важность?

Comment: @Abyx Вы [уверены](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/1GZe4l6DnrmVwV57)?

Comment: @Abyx указатель на функцию тоже можно создать с типом, отличным от int или double.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Есть четыре вида шаблонов - шаблоны функций, классов, переменных и псевдонимы типов (using), для разных видов шаблонов ограничения можно задавать по разному.

Само условие проверки лучше поместить в отдельный trait, чтобы не повторять это условие в каждом шаблоне на который надо наложить ограничения:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr bool is_int_or_double_v = 
    std::is_same<T, int>::value || std::is_same<T, double>::value;
```

### static_assert

Если цель - это выдать ошибку компиляции, то внутри тела шаблона функции и класса можно использовать `static_assert`.
Для шаблонов переменных надо использовать вспомогательную функцию, в которой будет `static_assert`, для псевдонимов (alias) можно использовать вспомогательный класс.

```
template<typename T>
struct X {
  static_assert(is_int_or_double_v<T>, "");
};

template<typename T>
void f() {
  static_assert(is_int_or_double_v<T>, "");
}
```

Однако в шаблонах класса static_assert срабатывает только при создании объектов, и он не помешает написать `X<float>* x;`.

### std::enable_if_t в параметре шаблона

Для генерации ошибки компиляции можно добавить шаблонный параметр со значением по умолчанию, но это меняет арность шаблона.

```
template<typename T, class=std::enable_if_t<is_int_or_double_v<T>>>
struct X {};

template<typename T, class=std::enable_if_t<is_int_or_double_v<T>>>
void f() {}

template<typename T, class=std::enable_if_t<is_int_or_double_v<T>>>
using id = T;

template<typename T, class=std::enable_if_t<is_int_or_double_v<T>>>
constexpr T v = 0;
```

Такую проверку можно обойти, явно указав этот параметр шаблона: `X<float, void>`.

### Прочие способы использования std::enable_if_t

`std::enable_if_t<condition, type>` можно использовать везде где ожидается тип - в базовых классах, возвращаемых значениях функций, параметрах по умолчанию функций, в псевдонимах:

```
struct empty {};
template<typename T>
struct X : std::enable_if_t<is_int_or_double_v<T>, empty> {};

template<typename T>
using id = std::enable_if_t<is_int_or_double_v<T>, T>;

template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<is_int_or_double_v<T>, void> f() {}

template<typename T>
void f(std::enable_if_t<is_int_or_double_v<T>>* = 0) {} // между * и = нужен пробел

template<typename T>
constexpr T v = (std::enable_if_t<is_int_or_double_v<T>>(), 0); // оператор "запятая"
```

### SFINAE

Функции могут быть перегружены, по этому для функций ошибка подстановки шаблона приводит только к тому что этот шаблон убирается из списка перегрузки (SFINAE). Это можно использовать совместно с удалением функций:

```
template<typename T, class=std::enable_if_t<!is_int_or_double_v<T>>, class=void>
void f() = delete;                       // ^ отрицание              ^ третий параметр

template<typename T, class=std::enable_if_t<is_int_or_double_v<T>>>
void f() {}
```

Для типов отличных от `int` и `double` будет использована первая перегрузка, которая удалена. Для `int` и `double` будет использована вторая.
Дополнительный (третий) параметр шаблона нужен чтобы шаблоны как-то отличались - в данном случае у них разная арность.

Этот код можно записать более просто:

```
template<typename T, class=std::enable_if_t<!is_int_or_double_v<T>>>
void f() = delete;                       // ^ отрицание

template<typename T>
void f() {}
```

Тогда при использовании `int` и `double` первая (удаленная) перегрузка будет прятаться, а при использовании других типов - она будет видна, и будет возникать ошибка "неоднозначный вызов перегруженной функции", потому что будут видны обе перегрузки.

Разумеется вторая перегрузка не обязательно должна быть удаленной. Можно использовать механизм SFINAE для того чтобы иметь одну перегрузку для `int` и `double`, а другую перегрузку - для остальных типов. Как писалось ранее, перегрузки должны чем-то отличаться, по этому у них должны быть разные сигнатуры, или разное количество или виды параметров шаблона:

```
template<typename T, class=std::enable_if_t<is_int_or_double_v<T>>>
void f() { /* int или double */ }

template<typename T, class=std::enable_if_t<!is_int_or_double_v<T>>, class=void>
void f() { /* другие типы */ }
// или
template<typename T, class=std::enable_if_t<!is_int_or_double_v<T>>, int=0>
void f() { /* другие типы */ }
// или
template<typename T, class=std::enable_if_t<!is_int_or_double_v<T>>>
void f(int=0) { /* другие типы */ }
```

В будущем (С++17 или позже) можно будет использовать *концепции*, которые заменят большинство использований enable_if, однако это будет нескоро (скорей всего вместе с Ranges TS).

Comment: Вместо использования `std::enable_if_t` в качестве параметров по умолчанию шаблонов можно использовать их в качестве параметров-нетипов: `template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<is_int_or_double_v<T>, int> = 0> void f();`. Тогда не придется вводить паразитные параметры шаблонов для обеспечения различия сигнатур шаблонных функций.

Answer (score 9):

Как вариант можно сделать проверку через `static_assert` :

```
template<typename T>
class Class
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<T, int>::value, "template instantiation of Class are not int");
};
```

варианты проверок типа так же могут быть `is_integral`, `is_base_of`

Answer (score 2):

Если разрешенных типов совсем немного, можно обойтись специализациями.

```
// Шаблонная функция
template <typename T>
void f(T);

template <>
void f(int) {}

template <>
void f(double) {}

// Шаблонный класс
template <typename T>
class C;

template <>
class C<int> {};

template <>
class C<double> {};
```

Для функций, однако, (как заметил @Abyx) для достижения нужного эффекта можно обойтись перегрузками, т.е. убрать строки `template <>`:

```
template <typename T>
void f(T);

void f(int) {}

void f(double) {}
```

В таком случае, вызов с любым другим типом, кроме `int` или `double` приведет для функций к ошибке линковщика. Т.к. общий шаблон функции не имеет реализации. А для классов - к ошибке компиляции.

При этом, стоит заметить, что специализации и перегруженные функции всё же могут существовать и параллельно:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void f(T);

template <>
void f(int) { std::cout << "spec\n"; }

void f(int) { std::cout << "fun\n"; }

int main() {
    f<int>(42); // spec
    f(42);      // fun
}
```

Для шаблонного класса (помимо варианта @Yuriy Orlov со `static_assert`) можно использовать специализацию в связке с `std::enable_if`:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, typename Enable = void>
class X; 

template<class T>
class X<T, typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_same<T,int>::value || 
    std::is_same<T,double>::value 
    >::type> 
{ }; 

int main() {
     X<double> xd; // ok
     X<int> xi;    // ok 
     X<long> xl;   // error
}
```

Хотя вариант со `static_assert` выглядит, имхо, элегантнее.

Comment: @Abyx в вопросе много чего не говорилось. В частности, и про идентичность/различие реализации для разных типов.