# Возможен ли шаблон со строго определёнными типами?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Есть функция, которая использует один из двух классов потомков и вызывается через `std::thread(MyFunc, std::ref(SpecifiedClassType)).detach()`;
У класса-родителя нет некоторых методов потомков, поэтому объявлять объекты потомков типом родителя не вариант.

**Можно ли как-то указать какие именно классы могут быть переменной в этой функции, или кроме `template<class T>` вариантов нет?**

Пояснение:

Есть класс `Capture` у которого два потомка - `Camera` и `Screen`. Назначение этой системы - получение кадров с камеры или скриншотов экрана - и более ничего (сети там быть не должно). У родителя есть общая для потомков функция `GrabJPG`, которая вызывается во внешней функции, в потоке. Я хочу, чтобы та функция `MyFunc`, что я упомянул в начале темы, выглядела примерно так:

```
void StreamThread(STREAMER &cgf, <только_тип_Camera_или_Screen> &source){
    // где cfg - структура с параметрами сетевой конфигурации,
    // а source - источник кадров - камера или экран.
    // ...
    cgf.connection->open(cgf.host, cgf.port)
    // ... туда-сюда настройки
    while (cgf.connection->active()){
    // ...
        int size = source->GrabJPG(&buffer);
        if( size){ cgf.connection->transmit(buffer, size); }
    // ...
    }
}
```

Сейчас у меня два таких абсолютно одинаковых `StreamThread`-а, различающихся только одной переменной - классом камеры или экрана. Не красиво, согласитесь? Должна быть ошибка компиляции, если попытаться засунуть в функцию любой другой класс, не являющийся потомком `Capture`. Вот, что требуется.

Comment: Предлагаю посмотреть на абстрактные методы.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Шаблоны в C++ Ограничение типа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/494672/%d0%a8%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%b2-c-%d0%9e%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%b0)

Comment: Т.е. у **всех** потомков метод есть, а у родителя - нет? А почему бы тогда не сделать, как говорит @Qwertiy? А если метод есть только у *некоторых* потомков, которые используются в функции - то имеет смысл сделать промежуточный класс с данным методом... По-моему, так...

Comment: Ничего не понятно. О какой "этой функции" идет речь? Об `std::thread` или о той, откуда это все вызывается? Откуда и к чему тут `template<class T>`? Приводите осмысленный контекст, а не какую-то кашу-размазню.

Comment: @AnT, шаблонная функция использует какую-то функцию. Он хочет ограничить шаблонный класс теми классами, у которых эта функция есть. Вроде всё понятно?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Нет, так понятно еще меньше.

Comment: @AnT, добавил общее описание алгоритма

Comment: @Qwertiy, добавил общее описание алгоритма

Comment: А я-то чего? Я и так вопрос понял.

Comment: По-прежнему не понятно: в чем важность того факта, что у классов потомков есть дополнительные функции, если вы их все равно не вызываете? В потоке, как вы сказали, вызывается только *общая* функция. Чем вас тогда не устраивает обычный классический полиморфизм через Capture? Тогда само собой получится ошибка, если вы попытаетесь засунуть туда объект класса не-наследника.

Comment: @AnT, У обоих наследников есть своя переопределённая функция `GrabBitmap`, у родителя она чисто виртуальная. и она вызывается в только родительской функции `GrabJPG`. Но у камеры есть ещё свои методы, которых нет больше нигде, поэтому я не могу написать что-то вроде `Capture * Cap = new Camera()`, так как родитель не увидит уникальных функций потомка. Может это и неправильная реализация наследования/полиморфизма. Но как тогда??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть несколько подходов к решению подобной проблемы:

#### [Явное инстанцирование](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Explicit_instantiation)

`+` Определения для обоих вариантов `StreamThread` будут сгенерированы автоматически на основе общего шаблонного кода с помощью директив явного инстанцирования (в том файле, где эти директивы будут указаны).

`+` (C++11 и выше) Неявное инстанцирование шаблона функции `StreamThread` для шаблонных аргументов `Camera` и `Screen` можно запретить во всех единицах трансляции, куда будет подключен заголовочный файл `StreamThread.h`.

`–` При попытке скомпилировать функцию `StreamThread` со значением шаблонного аргумента, отличного от `Camera` или `Screen`, будет выдана ошибка линковки (а не компиляции).

```
// StreamThread.h

template <typename Source>
void StreamThread(SREAMER &cgf, Source &source);

extern template void StreamThread(SREAMER &cgf, Camera &source); // C++11 и выше

extern template void StreamThread(SREAMER &cgf, Screen &source); // C++11 и выше


// StreamThread.cpp

template <typename Source>
void StreamThread(SREAMER &cgf, Source &source)
{
    // ...
}

template void StreamThread(SREAMER &cgf, Camera &source);

template void StreamThread(SREAMER &cgf, Screen &source);
```

#### Ограничение множества типов, которые могут использоваться в качестве аргумента шаблона, с помощью [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae)

При использовании данного подхода будут выдаваться ошибки компиляции в случае несовпадения аргумента шаблонной функции с `Camera` или `Screen`.

```
// StreamThread.h

#include <type_traits>

template <typename Source>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<Source, Camera> || std::is_same_v<Source, Screen>>
    StreamThread(SREAMER &cgf, Source &source)
{
    // ...
}
```

`+` При попытке скомпилировать функцию `StreamThread` со значением шаблонного аргумента, отличного от `Camera` или `Screen`, будет выдана ошибка компиляции (о том, что нужная перегрузка функции `StreamThread` не найдена).

`–` Шаблон функции `StreamThread` будет неявно инстанцирован во всех единицах трансляции, куда подключен заголовочный файл `StreamThread.h` и где происходит вызов функции `StreamThread`.

#### Комбинированный подход

Объединяет два предыдущих варианта и совмещает в себе их плюсы.

```
// StreamThread.h

#include <type_traits>

template <typename Source>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<Source, Camera> || std::is_same_v<Source, Screen>>
    StreamThread(SREAMER &cgf, Source &source);

extern template void StreamThread(SREAMER &cgf, Camera &source); // C++11 и выше

extern template void StreamThread(SREAMER &cgf, Screen &source); // C++11 и выше

// StreamThread.cpp

template <typename Source>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<Source, Camera> || std::is_same_v<Source, Screen>>
    StreamThread(SREAMER &cgf, Source &source)
{
    // ...
}

template void StreamThread(SREAMER &cgf, Camera &source);

template void StreamThread(SREAMER &cgf, Screen &source);
```

Comment: Не подскажете как это всё вызвать в потоке? У меня ошибку выдаёт `error: no matching function for call to std::thread::thread(<unresolved overloaded function type>, STREAMER&, Screen&)
                             if(!SCREEN.active){std::thread(StreamThread, SCREEN, (*screen)).detach();}`

Comment: @Iceman Во-первых, Вам необходимо явно указать, какую специализацию `StreamThread` Вы хотите использовать в качестве функции потока. Во-вторых, аргументы функции потока, которые передаются по ссылке, [должны оборачиваться в `std::ref`/`std::cref`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34078208/3043539) при передаче в конструктор `std::thread`: [пример](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ee0ffd84323e60de).

Comment: Отлично! Всё заработало! Спасибо Вам огромное!